# Runtime Error when user cancels inputbox to select date - can't find code to ignore when this happens

Tags: inputbox

vba 7+ 
The issue is when the input box cancel is selected. Seems to be a lot of methods posted to detect this, but none seem to work. Might have something to do with the formatting of the result syntax.

If anyone wants to give it a shot, here is the code:

```
Public Sub SelectDate()


 Dim strDate As Date


 strDate = InputBox("Select Report Date (mm/dd/yy)", "User date", Format(Now() - 1, "mm/dd/yy"))


   If IsDate(strDate) Then


    strDate = Format(CDate(strDate), "mm/dd/yy")


   Else


    MsgBox "Wrong date format"


   End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it...setting the variable as variant instead of Date type.

IE: dim strDate As Variant